# Need Urgent help in Creating in calling Standard Approve/Reject approval link page into Custom Link

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, salesforce-id

I am trying to call  Standard Approval "Approve/Reject" page  in Order Object related list through Custom outputLink in VF page.

Here in the URL i am trying to create:

```
<apex:outputLink value="+ 'URLENCODE{!("/p/process/ProcessInstanceWorkitemWizardStageManager?id='+{!o.ord.Id}+")}'+"> Aprovar/Rejeitar </apex:outputLink>
```

Please see the Value..

But its not working and not encoding the values properly..

Here is the Final Url that i am trying to create..

> /p/process/ProcessInstanceWorkitemWizardStageManager?id=04ie0000000NeFI

Where 04ie0000000NeFI is the id of order record..

Please help asap,thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the url you are trying to get, I think that this might work for you:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/p/process/ProcessInstanceWorkitemWizardStageManager?id={!o.ord.Id}"> Aprovar/Rejeitar </apex:outputLink>
```

I think I found the problem. I set up something similar in my org, and I got the following error message:

> Unable to Access Page
>
> The value of the "id" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed
>   length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the
>   value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to
>   our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were
>   requesting as well as any other related information.

The problem is that the id needs to be a ProcessInstanceWorkitem id, rather than the id of the order associated with it.

Comment: Thanks for your Help, that was the exact issue and it worked..